# is there any Perl Module to replace the old mirror module?

Tags: linux, perl, module, mirror

Recently I need to touch a very old system running over the past 15 years with some Perl programs. Sadly I have very few experience using Perl as a program language.

In the program the module [mirror](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/utils/archivers/mirror/mirror-faq.html) is used quite often. Obviously it is very old, and refers to some modules I guess is also outdated.

Is there any newer module with similar functions and also easy to use?

Thanks

Comment: [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) is a sophisticated multiprotocol client that allows mirroring remote directories.

Comment: @oalders, can rsync runs over ftp?

Comment: @Winston If you're bound to using ftp as your protocol of choice, rsync is not for you.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Comment: @salva, thanks, I turn to use lftp to do the mirroing

Answer (score 1):

When I use `cpanp` and `m mirror`, it lists some 88 modules with 'mirror' somewhere in the name.

These ones might be of relevance to your purposes:

```
39 Net::MirrorDir                                          0.20     KNORR     
40 Net::MirrorDir::Connection                              0.20     KNORR     
41 Net::MirrorDir::Exclusions                              0.20     KNORR     
42 Net::MirrorDir::LocalDir                                0.20     KNORR     
43 Net::MirrorDir::RemoteDir                               0.20     KNORR     
44 Net::MirrorDir::Subset                                  0.20     KNORR
```

The chances are high that if you try to install [`Net::MirrorDir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3AMirrorDir), all the other modules will come along for the ride.  I've not investigated the package further than that, and there are other sets of modules that might be of relevance as alternatives (plus a whole lot that probably won't be of any help at all).  Some of the others mention 'rsync' in the title.